# save align.plot()

Tags: r, ggplot2

Have to plots:

```
pl1 <- qplot(x=trade.date, y=price1, data=finalfutff, geom='line')+scale_y_continuous(name='')+scale_x_date(name='', expand=c(0,0))+opts(panel.background=theme_rect(),panel.grid.major=theme_blank(), panel.grid.minor=theme_blank(), plot.margin = unit(c(1,0,0,0), "lines"))
```

and

```
pl2 <- qplot(x=trade.date, y=adj1, data=finalfutff, geom='line')+scale_y_continuous(name='')+scale_x_date(name='', expand=c(0,0))+opts(panel.background=theme_rect(),panel.grid.major=theme_blank(), panel.grid.minor=theme_blank(), plot.margin = unit(c(1,0,0,0), "lines"))
```

Use `align.plot (from ggExtra)` to align the plots (instead of facet_grid because I like to have ticks and text on the x axis on all plots), but when I try to save the file with ggsave:

```
ggsave(plot=align.plot(pl1, pl2), "file.png", width=9.8, height=6.9)
```

i get:

```
Error in ggsave(plot = align.plots(pl1, pl2), filename = "file.png",  : 
  plot should be a ggplot2 plot
```

How to save a align.plot?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just use `grid.arrange()` (instead of `align.plot()`), and use standard `png` device instead of `ggsave()` which expect ggplot objects?

```
dsamp <- diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ]
p1 <- qplot(carat, price, data=dsamp, colour=clarity)
p2 <- qplot(carat, price, data=dsamp, colour=clarity, geom="path")
library(gridExtra)
png("a.png")
grid.arrange(p1, p2) # add ncol=2 to arrange as two-column
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, but the "standard" resolution is not very good. How do I get width=9.8 and height=6.9 in inches?

Comment: @fredrik : see the help page of png (`?png`). We're not going to read the manual for you.

Comment: setting: png(filename="testp.png", width=2940, height=2070), the axis and text becomes very thin/small... not like with ggsave... what to do, if I still want to "see" the axis and text...?

Comment: another problem I see now, the graphs are not align, so I guess that's why I have to use align.plots().....

Comment: @baptiste Not in my case at least (R 2.13, gridExtra 0.8 from R-forge, ggplot2 0.8.9 from CRAN).

Comment: @chl well, the following should work, 
ggsave("test.pdf", arrangeGrob(qplot(1,1), qplot(1:10)))
however, you need to explicitly pass the arrangeGrob; it does not default to the last grid.arrange() call (this is on purpose, I don't think grid.arrange should touch last_plot())

Answer (score 1):

**Edited**

The call to `ggsave` with `align.plots` doesn't work because `align.plots` doesn't return an object of class ggplot.

This means you will have to make a call to one of the plot devices, e.g. `png` or `pdf`.  For example:

```
png("filename.png")
align.plots(pl1, pl2)
dev.off()
```

Refer to `?png` for options to specify height, width, dpi, etc.  You will probably want to specify height and width explicitly, unless you want to use the default settings of 7 inches.

For a list and links to all the plot devices supported by R (i.e. png, pdf, etc.) see `?Devices`

Comment: Ah, that's because align.plots() doesn't return a ggplot object.  I shall modify my answer.

Comment: @Andrie: do you know how to "keep" the thickness of the axis and size of the axis.text when I put width=2940 and height=2070. When I use facet_grid and ggsave, the thickness and size of the characters are kept the same "size". When using png() they become very thin/small

Comment: It's because you have specified a gigantically enormous plot 74 meters wide.  Read the help file for ?png and pay special attention how width and height should be specified.

Comment: @Andrie My +1 for the added explanation and those benevolent advices.